# Why is the RTCPeerConnection throwing a readonly error while setting remoteDescription?

Tags: react-native, webrtc, typeerror, mqtt, readonly

I've been experiencing a bug that's driving me mad. I'm using the `react-native-native-mqtt` library as the signalling server for WebRTC. When my client receives the offer and attempts to set it as its `remoteDescription`, it reports a `TypeError: Attempting to assign to readonly property`

I'm totally at a loss for why this is happening. The offer message looks okay:

```
{"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 3320413992579928282 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE video\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS ef72de95-9b7f-4f54-a0c9-d3ac34d96ce4\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 35 36 100 101 127 123 125\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Da7B\r\na=ice-pwd:rA/sO+zZRQe6wLIMlpMLjk1K\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 7B:95:58:16:3E:EA:BB:3E:E1:26:A0:00:16:64:F2:AE:F5:BD:85:09:7B:69:C1:F0:EE:57:35:22:69:9F:56:E8\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:video\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=extmap:4 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type\r\na=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing\r\na=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space\r\na=sendonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:97 apt=96\r\na=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\na=rtpmap:35 AV1X/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:35 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:35 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:35 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:35 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:35 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:36 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:36 apt=35\r\na=rtpmap:100 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:101 apt=100\r\na=rtpmap:127 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:123 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:123 apt=127\r\na=rtpmap:125 ulpfec/90000\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 82128400 3807267395\r\na=ssrc:82128400 cname:aH3HJqsqmi6MlTCc\r\na=ssrc:82128400 msid:ef72de95-9b7f-4f54-a0c9-d3ac34d96ce4 725a36b4-6896-48ff-bdfa-56f2620dfcd3\r\na=ssrc:82128400 mslabel:ef72de95-9b7f-4f54-a0c9-d3ac34d96ce4\r\na=ssrc:82128400 label:725a36b4-6896-48ff-bdfa-56f2620dfcd3\r\na=ssrc:3807267395 cname:aH3HJqsqmi6MlTCc\r\na=ssrc:3807267395 msid:ef72de95-9b7f-4f54-a0c9-d3ac34d96ce4 725a36b4-6896-48ff-bdfa-56f2620dfcd3\r\na=ssrc:3807267395 mslabel:ef72de95-9b7f-4f54-a0c9-d3ac34d96ce4\r\na=ssrc:3807267395 label:725a36b4-6896-48ff-bdfa-56f2620dfcd3\r\n"}
```

and this is my `acceptOffer` function:

```
const handleOffer = offer => {
    peerConn.setRemoteDescription(offer).then(() => {
      peerConn
        .createAnswer({
          mandatory: {
            OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
            OfferToReceiveVideo: true,
          },
        })
        .then(answer => {
          peerConn.setLocalDescription(answer).then(() => {
            sendMqttMessage({
              type: 'answer',
              answer: answer,
            });
          });
        });
    });
  };
```

And here is the function generating the offer:

```
const handleCall = () => {
    setCallActive(true);
    peerConn
      .createOffer({
        mandatory: {
          OfferToReceiveVideo: false,
          OfferToReceiveAudio: false,
        },
      })
      .then(offer => {
        peerConn.setLocalDescription(offer).then(() => {
          sendMqttMessage({
            type: 'offer',
            offer: offer,
            name: userId,
          });
        });
      });
  };
```

For reference, I'm using the `react-native-webrtc` library here: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc

Here's the log as well

[image: error_log]

Thank you!

Comment: apparently fixed in the latest version thereof, what version are you trying?

Comment: Sorry for not listing it. I'm using `react-native-webrtc` version 1.92.2 and `react-native-native-mqtt` version 0.1.8

Comment: Seems to be steming from the `use-strict` command in the `RTCSessionDescription`